# Is it good practice to scale mobile web page to 0.5?

Tags: html, viewport, retina-display, mobile-webkit

I'm developing webapps for mobile devices (mainly iPhone and android). But the css px is not device px which depends on window.devicePixelRatio(2 for iPhone4S). Our designers are always making design based on screen of 640 x 960(iPhone4S screen). So the size I use in my css is half of that specified in the design. When it comes to 1 device px border, 0.5px in css means no border. I found 2 solutions(box-shadow, and border-image) achieve 1 retina px border after searching the web, but the implementation is ugly.

So I set the initial-scale as 0.5 in the viewport, now the size in my css is identical to web-design, and 1 retina px border is natural to implement.

Is this a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

If the only device you want to use the page is an iPhone 4/5, then this should be almost totally fine.

But if your company is looking for pages that are responsive (fit multiple screens at multiple resolutions), then the company's starting point should be to accept that those designs can't match the real world (or there will have to be more of them made, at different resolutions)...

The technical starting point is to set

```
<meta name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width,
               initial-scale=1.0,
               minimum-scale=1.0">
```

There might be reasons to use other settings, sometimes, but typically, this is the starting point.

It says that you should use the CSS pixels of the device's browser as the device's width, and set the initial zoom to 100% width, and set the minimum-zoom ("zoom-out") to 100% width.

The reasons for this are pretty simple when you get to the math;
The iPhone 4/5 have a width of 640px and a CSS-width of 320px.
That's 50% width of a 640 design (a 2:1 dot-per-px ratio)...
...but the Galaxy S4 has a 1080px screen with 360px CSS-width (33.3%, 3:1 ratio).

So do you set the scale to 0.5 or 0.333?

Maybe there are cases where this does matter, because of how a desktop site is currently made, and it can't squeeze down past a certain minimum-width.

But in typical designs that are looking to be adaptive, you would start with the device deciding how wide it should be, and and your design fitting into that width as well as it can.

Again, this often means responsive design using percents or em/rem for the widths of objects, with breakpoints in media queries to target different layout designs.

So you might have designers make a design at 320 for 320-480, one for 480px up to 640px, etc...
...or maybe you just have views that get smaller and smaller, once you're thinner than an iPad.

It's all up to you, your designers and your company.
But this, at least, is how projects are often started, and is the idea behind them.

Comment: For consistent visual size, I'll always set the scale to 0.5 no matter what the device pixel ratio is.

Comment: @Kevin In your example of a 2px border, then, the iPhone would get a 1px border.  That's fine.  The S4 would get a 0.666px border. How does that work out? The answer is "unpredictably". I mean, you can predict how a given browser is going to render something like that, if you know how the browser deals with sub-pixel rendering, and you know where in the sub-pixel grid your 1/Xpx border sits... That's fine, for a browser, but not all browsers on all devices treat all rendering the same; especially not at sub-pixel precision.